# Dreamweaver does not preview PHP correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, dreamweaver

I have a local instance of XAMPP 5.6.2 running for Dreamweaver to use as a testing server.  When I navigate to my PHP web page through a browser, the PHP script runs correctly (connecting to a MySQL DB) so I don't think there is any issue with the script.

However when Dreamweaver tries to preview it "live", it will preview correctly the first time it is loaded, but subsequent loads the PHP script is displayed as text only after about halfway through.  What could be causing this?

Here is the code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

(Sorry I am new to SO so I cannot post images yet, the below are links only).

The Resulting page when navigated to through chrome:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4l14fcegzm7fbyf/SO_DW%20PHP%20not%20loading_Chrome%20View.PNG?dl=0

The Resulting page when navigated to through Dreamweaver live preview:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ij2gftp1eyrv2bb/SO_DW%20PHP%20not%20loading_DW%20View.PNG?dl=0

Comment: It looks like Dreamweaver is not parsing the php code, as it is treating the `>` in `$conn->connect_error` as a html closing tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919845/how-to-set-up-php-test-server-in-dreamweaver

Comment: Thanks Sean any idea why it might do that?

Comment: Thanks Nick G.  That is how I set up my testing server.  After re-reading your link I did a little more experimenting and found that: A) This is only an issue when I have a different server as my 'Remote' than my 'Testing'.  When I made my local instance of XAMPP both my 'Remote' server and my 'Testing' server the issues goes away.  and B) Even when I do have different 'remote' and 'testing' servers, the PHP script is processed correctly the first time dreamweaver is loaded.